# Android Porting on Telechips TCC89XX: Not able to start init process

Tags: android, sockets, sdk, arm

I have started to port Android on TCC89XX board, I download Android SDK. and applied the patch with kernel 2.6.29, the Processor is having armv6 instruction set.

I am not able to see the network up ifconfig is not able to show the network devices.

Also I do not get why there is no "on" binary in the system/bin, system/xbin, the init.rc and init.goldfish.rc.

I cannot get the zygote process up. create_socket throws error.

If any one knows about this, please tell what i need to do correctly or point me to some correct URL's which will be help full

thanks
Suman

Answer (score 0):

when you say android sdk do you mean telechips android bsp or are you using the linux bsp? There is no "on" binary in linux that I'm aware of, have you tried -a with ifconfig as a device that is in a down state will not show with default ifconfig , the -a is show all.

Comment: Hi when you say android sdk do you mean telechips android bsp or are you using the linux bsp?